# Wordpress on Azure Linux App Service over https

Tags: wordpress, azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I ran into a problem hosting WordPress on an Azure Linux App Service.  Wordpress wasn't recognizing that we were over https.  All of my stylesheets were loaded over http even though the site was requested over https.

I found this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl and this code snippet:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

I also ran across this code on github that basically does the same thing:

https://gist.github.com/buchizo/1b619c5461295822f0c45e666ba716bf

```
if ( array_key_exists( "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER", $_SERVER ) ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' ) {
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
    }
    define( "WP_SITEURL", "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"] );
    define( "WP_HOME", "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"] );
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] =  $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"];
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] =  $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"];
} else {
    define( "WP_SITEURL", "http://yoursite.azurewebsites.net" );
    define( "WP_HOME", "http://yoursite.azurewebsites.net" );
}
```

After inserting this code in my wp-config.php file, everything started working.

My question is this, why is this required?  What is special about Azure that it requires this?  The GitHub link references nginx.  That's a load balancer as I understand it, but I haven't configured a load balancer on Azure anywhere.  I'd love for someone to explain the network topography in play here.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, not on Azure though but on a virtual server running inside my organisation network. Usually there is a load balancer for external traffic coming from the Internet. There might be a load balancer that you have not configured but is controlled by Azure. The reason is in such situations, the $_SERVER array has the IP address or the URL of your server (where WordPress is running) as the HTTP_HOSTNAME. WordPress reads this as the main website URL and redirects you to it, or loads the stylesheets based on it (hence no https).

The second code block tries to detect if the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER key exists and use it as an indicator that the request might have been forwarded by a load balancer or a proxy server. Therefore it swaps the value with the value of HTTP_HOST key on $_SERVER.

Here is an instance from wp-login.php on how WordPress figures out the base URL:

```
if ( force_ssl_admin() && ! is_ssl() ) {
if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( set_url_scheme( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'https' ) );
    exit;
} else {
    wp_safe_redirect( 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    exit;
}
```

}